# x86 assembly, how to add variables stored in memory?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

PLATFORM: Pentium 4 processor (i really need to upgrade :) running Windows XP. I am currently assembling with MASM32.

I am an absolute beginner with assembly and I am trying to figure out how to add variables. I understand how to define variables, place data in a register, and how to place registers in the stack, but I don't know how to combine the values of two variables (by adding).

Also, could anyone give me a link or something to an easy to understand tutorial on x86 assembly, all the ones that I've found so far are really high-level stuff and they don't explain much. That would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Progrmr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple addition:

```
add eax, ebx   ; Adds eax and ebx and stores the result in eax
```

Load from memory, then add, then store in memory:

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR [esi]    ; Load a double word from memory into eax
mov ebx, DWORD PTR [edi]    ; Load a double word from memory into ebx
add eax, ebx                ; Adds eax and ebx and stores the result in eax
mov DWROD PTR[esi], eax     ; Store a double word in eax into memory
```

In the examples above, DWORD PTR isn't strictly needed, but is a good habit to practice because it remove any ambiguity and makes code easier to read.

It's important to remember that you can only add registers of the same size (DWORD in the examples above). If you want to add two registers of different sizes:

```
mov al, BYTE PTR [esi]    ; Loads a single byte from memory into al
mov bx, WORD PTR [edi]    ; Loads a word from memory into bx
movzx eax, al             ; Zero extends al into the entire eax register
movzx ebx, bx             ; Zero extends bx into the entire ebx register
add eax, ebx              ; Adds eax and ebx and stores the result in eax
```

This isn't a terribly good example because there are easier ways to do the same thing, but hopefully it'll show some of the tricks you can use.

You can also add a memory value to a registers:

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR [esi]     ; Load a double word from memory into eax
add eax, DWORD PTR [edi]     ; Add a double word in memory to eax
```

Here's a good site to use as a reference: http://ref.x86asm.net/

Comment: Thanks heaps! This was helpful. What do you mean by "there are easier ways to do the same thing". Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: And also, when i add two numbers, how would I go about placing that value in a variable and displaying that variable to the console? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of a separate mov/movzx instruction, you can simply do this: movzx eax, BYTE PTR [esi]. As for getting and printing from the console, try this link: http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=1094.0

Comment: You can and should `movzx eax, BYTE PTR [esi]` instead of inefficiently merging into the old contents of EAX with `mov` to `al`, and then using a separate movzx into the same register (which even defeats mov-elimination on Intel SnB-family which can run `movzx ecx, al` with zero latency, but not `movzx ecx, cl`.)  **Anyway, use zero-extending loads for narrow data.**  (Or sign-extending if that's what you want.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I even stated in my answer that "This isn't a terribly good example because there are easier ways to do the same thing". My examples were for illustrative purposes to show that opcodes that can be used and how without being too verbose.

Comment: Stack Overflow answers should avoid anti-patterns when demoing combinations of features.  Some beginners won't realize you could have used a memory source `movzx`, and/or won't realize the subtleties of exactly how bad this is for byte loads.  Showing a bad way to do something and then saying "this is bad" in a paragraph of text is a lot less useful than showing a good way in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you conceptual problem. x86 values live in registers or memory, the concept of a variable is higher level. One way to add values is to put them into registers and then call the add operation.

http://computertech.createmybb3.com/showthread.php?tid=116